# Transforming a sum of products of binomial coefficients gives only partially determined expression

Tags: special-functions, summation

On 11.0.1.0,

```
Sum[Binomial[n + 3, i] Binomial[n, k - i] 2^i, {i, 0, k}]
```

gives

```
Binomial[n, k] Hypergeometric2F1[-k, -3 - n, 1 - k + n, 2]
```

The latter expression evaluates correctly only when $k\leqslant n$ or $k>2n+3$ (in the latter case it is 0). For $n<k\leqslant2n+3$ it results in `Indeterminate`.

Answer to the equivalent sum

```
Sum[Binomial[n + 3, n + 3 - k + i] Binomial[n, i] 2^(k - i), {i, 0, k}]
```

performs slightly better, it is

```
2^k Binomial[3 + n, 3 - k + n] Hypergeometric2F1[-k, -n, 4 - k + n, 1/2]
```

which evaluates correctly for $k\leqslant n+3$, but when $n+3<k\leqslant2n+3$ it also gives `Indeterminate`.

The same happens with some other equivalent sums that I tried. Is there a way to obtain an expression without summation that always works?

Comment: Use: `Limit`,For example: `Limit[Binomial[n, k] Hypergeometric2F1[-k, -3 - n, 1 - k + n, 2], 
  k -> 2] /. n -> 1` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk This also gives `Indeterminate` for the same values

Comment: For me works fine.I using Mathematica `12.0`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I see. Maybe some bug that was eliminated in version 12?

Comment: `2^(-4 + k - 2 n) Binomial[3 + n, 3 - k + n] Hypergeometric2F1[4 + n, 4 - k + 2 n, 4 - k + n, 1/2]` does a little better than your last expression, but there still are cases where it returns `Indeterminate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand) to the expression with an explicit value of `k`, but with `n` undefined, then you should be able to get rid of the 0/0 issues:

```
sum[n_, k_] := Block[{m},
    FunctionExpand[Binomial[m,k] Hypergeometric2F1[-k,-3-m,1-k+m,2]] /. m->n
]
```

Examples:

```
sum[1,2]
sum[1,5]
sum[1,6]
sum[2,7]
sum[2,8]
```

> 32
>
> 16
>
> 0
>
> 32
>
> 0

Comment: Thank you, it works, although with some error messages before giving the answer. They disappear if I add `Factor@` before `FunctionExpand`.